# Peano Induction Axiom

Tags: induction, peano-axioms

This is a typical rendition the Peano Axiom of Induction:

If subset $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ contains $1$ and is closed under the successor function (i.e., $n \in S$ implies $\sigma\text{n} \in S$ where $\sigma$ is the successor function) then that subset $S$ is all of $\mathbb{N}$.

How do we make the leap that $S$, which might not be all of $\mathbb{N}$ eventually does cover all of $\mathbb{N}$? I can only assume $\sigma\text{n}$ takes things outside of $S$?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. Why do you assume that $\sigma n$ is outside $S$? You've just said that $S$ is closed under taking successors...

Comment: Are you trying to *prove* an axiom?

Answer (score 3):

> How do we make the leap that $S$, which might not be all of $\mathbb{N}$ eventually does cover all of $\mathbb{N}$? I can only assume $\sigma n$ takes things outside of $S$?

When you say that "$S$..might not be all of $\mathbb{N}$", you are actually trying to find out whether $S$ and $\mathbb{N}$ are identical or not. In other words, you need a *proof* of the question whether $S=\mathbb{N}$ or not. But you can only prove the equality between two sets when you know that definition of each set. So, you need to answer first,

> What is the definition of $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 0):

It follows from the definition of the natural numbers. $\mathbb{N}$ is defined as the smallest set containing 0 (or 1, if you insist on starting at 1) and closed under successors.

If that answer isn't satisfactory, then assume $S \subset \mathbb{N}$ is a strict subset (so $S \neq \mathbb{N}$). Let $k$ be the least element of $\mathbb{N} \setminus S$. Then either $k = 1$ or there is a natural number $n$ such that $\sigma n = k$. By the definition of $k$, $n \in S$, and since $S$ is closed under successors, $\sigma n = k \in S$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: How do you know $\mathbb{N}\backslash S$ has a least element? Well ordering is logically equivalent to mathematical induction. You cannot use it to justify that induction works, which is what I am guessing the OP is asking for.

Comment: This is part of the point: we either need to take induction as an axiom, or as part of the definition of the natural numbers, or we take something equivalent.

Comment: @Athar Adbul-Quader Yes, I think I see now. If $S$ begins with $1$ (or $0$), and it is closed under the succession function $\sigma$, that really means $\sigma$ will always allow total coverage of $\mathbb{N}$. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what "$\sigma$ will always allow total coverage of $\mathbb{N}$" means. But the point is you have to really look at the definition of the set of natural numbers, which usually will have some inductive flavor to it.

Answer (score -1):

The Peano Induction Axiom can be thought of as one of the 5 essential properties of the natural numbers. See [Peano's Axioms](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PeanosAxioms.html). (There are other, less widely used formulations.)

The Induction Axiom says that, if you have a subset $P$ of $\mathbb{N}$, then we can show that all elements of $\mathbb{N}$ will be in $P$ if

(a) $1 \in P$, and

(b) if $x \in P$, then the successor of $x$ will also be in $P$

Comment: I can't make any sense of this other than if you say $P$ is a subset, and you say $x \in P$, and you provide a successor $\sigma$ function, then eventually some $\sigma x$ will indeed go beyond some original idea of $P$ being a true subset $P \subset \mathbb{N}$. That is, this a contradiction of sorts..

Comment: @147pm Are you aware of the fact that every set is a subset of itself? For any set $X$, we have $X\subset X$.

Comment: As I'm saying, a successor function insures that the contents of $P$ will have everything $\mathbb{N}$ has. You start out "doubting," questioning $P$ has everything, but if $P$ starts with $1$ and has a successor function, $P$ must "eventually" have all the natural numbers of $\mathbb{N}$. Is this a correct interpretation?